# how can I increase failure tolerance for spark jobs on yarn? Job failed due to too many preemntions?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, preemption

How can I increase failure tolerance on yarn? In a busy cluster my job fails due to too many failures. Most of the failures were due to `Executor lost` base by preemption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have preemption enabled you really should be using the external shuffle service to avoid these issues. There's really not much that can be done otherwise.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14209 - JIRA talks about.

Comment: Is this specific to spark? Why does hive seem to be not affected? Without the external shuffle service still works fine?

Comment: Also, is there something like `spark.task.maxFailures` for stage failures?

Comment: `spark.stage.maxConsecutiveAttempts` looks like a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Close yarn preemption?Or run smaller jobs to avoid complete recomputation?

Comment: well that's definitely an option but not desirable ( both) nor do I have permissions to self-manage yarn queue settings ;) . Are there other possibilities?  `spark.yarn.max.executor.failures` sounds interesting.